# Can't get setFrame to work (or setBounds, or .frame, for that matter...)

Tags: objective-c, uiview

I've been searching for a solution on this but I'm stumped... I have a UIView that I've initialized with a frame, and now I need to resize that frame, but I am having no luck at all:

Assuming that listItem_Y and listItem_Height both contain values (which they do) can anyone explain what I'm missing to resize the view?

```
primaryColumnListItems.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, primaryColumnListItems.frame.size.width, listItem_Y + listItem_Height);

[primaryColumnListItems setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, primaryColumnListItems.frame.size.width, listItem_Y + listItem_Height)];
```

Neither variation of bounds is working for me either.

Thanks

Comment: How did you initialize the frame?  Where is this code being called?  If primaryColumnListItems is an IBOutlet, is it hooked up in IB?  Did you make sure primaryColumnListItems is not nil at this point?

Comment: primaryColumnListItems is initialized via code (I'm not using IB at all at the moment.)

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, I'm a goofball... It was a casting issue with values stored as ints needing to be typecast to CGFloats.